# Empirical support for multivariate time series forecasting with vertically stacked data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references

I was working on a project where we're using several multivariate time series and stacking them vertically (i.e. concatenating them) and passing them to some packages that can do some kind of prediction [1][2]. They call it "Global Models".

The concept of multivariate time series is not new to me, but I would like to know if there's any empirical/theoretical support from any area (e.g. statistics, econometrics, operational research) for that approach.

On top of my head, I can only imagine that unless that forecast is based in some kind of Splines[3] several issues can happen, like heterosckedacity, multicollinearity, and so on.

[1] - https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/01-multi-time-series-and-covariates.html#Global-Forecasting-Models

[2] - https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/850#issuecomment-1072160643

[3] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a few years ago, it seemed like "local" models (separate models per time series, e.g., Exponential Smoothing, ARIMA, or separate dynamic regressions) would usually outperform "global" ones. However, the recent [M4](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-forecasting/vol/36/issue/1) and [M5](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-forecasting/vol/38/issue/4) forecasting competitions were quite decisively won by "global" methods - specifically by a smart combination of "classical" methods and DL for the M4, and by variants of Boosting for the M5.

Incidentally, I believe the difference between "local" and "global" models was first articulated by [Januschowski & Kolassa (2019, *Foresight: The International Journal of Applied Forecasting*)](https://ideas.repec.org/a/for/ijafaa/y2019i52p36-43.html) and [Januschowski et al. (2020, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.05.008) in the context of an invited commentary on the M4 competition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stephan Kolassa.

Based on the links that you sent, I found a reference regarding this vertically stacked time series that is called "Investigating the accuracy of cross-learning time series forecasting methods.".




[1] - Semenoglou, Artemios-Anargyros, et al. "Investigating the accuracy of cross-learning time series forecasting methods." International Journal of Forecasting 37.3 (2021): 1072-1084. Link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169207020301850